# Script to pick up the HTML value of a page? Explanation inside

Tags: javascript, html

I am quite the noob at anything other than some HTML, CSS etc, basic website stuff. My javascript is pretty non-existant too. However we were quoted £2,500 by the people who develop our website to add Paypal on the checkout page! They use a fancy 3rd party program which is a standalone software made by themselves that contains all the products etc. We pay monthly to have access to that and make all website changes (such as price, product name etc) in that.

To cut a long story short, I had a look around and found this:

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=YOUR_MERCHANT_ID"
data-button="buynow"
data-name="My product"
data-amount="1.00"
async
></script>
```

Now, can I change the data-amount field to pick up what the "value" is on the page in the HTML? That way I can simply just add a button that picks that up. Which would work with paypal.

```
<div class='basketLabel'>Total Amount To Pay:</div>
<span>&pound;</span>1,038.00</li>
<input type=hidden name='amount' value='1,038.00'>
```

Basically, how can I get the javascript code to pick up the value from the HTML (or somewhere else). I only have access to the full HTML of the page.

Comment: if jquery is included, try $("script[src=paypal*]").data("amount", $("input[name=amount]").val());

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how many of these data fields you have on a page but you could write a JS method to dynamically assign the values of the given HTML.

I would start by giving the HTML you're working with some ID's.

```
<script id="paypalScript" src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=YOUR_MERCHANT_ID"
 data-button="buynow"
 data-name="My product"
 data-amount="1.00"
 async
 onload="assignAmount"
></script>

<div class='basketLabel'>Total Amount To Pay:</div>
<span>&pound;</span>1,038.00</li>
<input id="amount" type=hidden name='amount' value='1,038.00'>
```

Then write a method to execute onload.

```
function assignAmount(){
   var amtElm = document.getElementById('amount');
   var scriptElm = document.getElementById('paypalScript');

   scriptElm.dataset.amount = amtElm.value;
}
```

Then attach the method to the onload event of the script element. Putting the script tag below your data field in the HTML should prevent any load issues you might run into.

Comment: Hey, this could work, but wouldn't creating an id of the basketLabel div mean that i'd have to do it manually for the several thousand products on the website? (Inputting the value for each one manually)

Comment: We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with the PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the seller to resolve the problem. If this payment is for an eBay listing, you can contact the seller via the "Ask Seller a Question" link on the listing page. When you have the correct email address, payment can be made at www.paypal.com.

I get this from paypal after doing as you ask and clicking the button, I feel we're getting close though!

Comment: It picked up the $1.00 in the data-amount instead of the value

Comment: I don't think I have a clear picture of your problem but the ID correlates to HTML data holder. The number of ID's purely based on how many of these items you'd have on a single page. If multiple exists, then yes another method would be required.